# filling holes in bathroom tile

Tags: bathroom, repair, tile, floor

When you walk in our bathroom on the tiles with high heels, it puts a hole in the tile. It seems likely the tiles were not meant to be for floor. Regardless, we'd like to find some way to fill in the holes with either plaster or something otherwise. What would be best to use?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate i'm not entirely sure. I'll add a picture.

Comment: Can you leave your solution as an answer?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Cork? That's actually pretty funny.

Comment: @craig -- pics weren't up when I asked, but since you pointed it out, I'm gonna go delete my first comment...

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I **still** think it's pretty funny. ;-)  I agree with you, though, that it's probably some soft soapstone/limestone or travertine type of material.

Comment: Whatever material it is, it appears that it is not supported by a flat substrate (see pictures 2 & 3). Patching is good, I guess, but to prevent future occurrence would require removal and replacement, with appropriate tile and sturdy flat substrate.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Standard installation with a tile trowel leaves gaps regardless of the substrate, and with a small-pointed high heel you could step right on one of the gaps. Although that top picture with the broken-off edge kind of looks like the mortar wasn't even pulled clear out to the edge of the tile, and these tiles are clearly not a hard, durable material.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this as an answer with trepidation and the hope that a real tile expert will chime in.

My guess is that they're limestone or travertine. If you have spares, grind/smash/pulverize them to dust, mix that with a 2 part epoxy and fill 'er up. (Same for the broken chips at the door -- glue them solidly down with granite-safe adhesive and fill the cracks after the glue cures.) I don't have personal experience with this product, so not a recommendation (hopefully, someone else will chime in), but I'd be willing to try "Tenax Travertine Filler" (available on amazon).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If properly installed, this tile should never break under normal use. This is a defect in workmanship. The installer did not put down enough thinset under the tiles which caused them to have large voids under them. You can see the void in your pictures, and it is especially visible in the last photo.

At this point there is not much you can do beyond replacing the entire floor. You will most likely continue to have issues with the tiles cracking or breaking.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion You should replace the bathroom tile all together is the best thing to do. If this is not possible for financial or aesthetic reasons, injecting an epoxy glue solution underneath the tile to re-bond it to the sub floor is the only other option.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm seeing this correctly it looks like the tile was put down on top of carpet.  If that's the case, than that's the problem.  There isn't a solid base and when you step on the floor your heels or sharp edges go right through it.  Also, these may be the inexpensive tile floor pieces that they sell at Lowes or Home Depot.  They cost about $1.00 each and look like real tiles but are some form of plastic.

Comment: It's definitely not on top of carpet. Looks like it's on top of a gypsum version of a leveling compound.